# Dynamic Sp_Executesql failing on datetime conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dynamic-sql

I have a very simple dynamic SQL query that specifically needs to be called using sp_executesql with parameters. This query works fine in regular dynamic SQL, but fails when using sp_executesql on a conversion error.

I have tried many combinations of dynamic SQL, but none of them seem to work specifically for datetime conversions related to sp_executesql.

```
declare 
@sql_nvarchar nvarchar(max),
@datetime datetime = GETDATE(),
@sqlparams nvarchar(max),
@tablename nvarchar(max) = 'SomeTableName'

Set @sql_nvarchar =
N'
Select *
from ' + @tablename + '
where Date > ''' + convert(nvarchar(23), @datetime, 101) + ''' '

Set @sqlparams =
N'
@datetime datetime,
@tablename nvarchar(max)
'

EXEC(@sql_nvarchar)

EXEC [sp_executesql] @sql_nvarchar,@sqlparams, @datetime, @tablename
```

The first exec correctly returns the desired query, the second EXEC throws an error: 'Error converting data type nvarchar(max) to datetime.'

Comment: Your query works when I run it. Are you sure the `Date` column of `SomeTableName` is of type `datetime`?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, if I add a temp table #SomeTableName, both EXECs complete without error, but I still see the error message when I replace #SomeTableName with a production table that has a datetime field with the correct field name referenced.

Comment: @DaleBurrell How do I get the parameters to be passed in? I don't want to use a static query for testing because the whole issue is that I can get it to work in regular and dynamic sql, just not sp_executesql.

Comment: Why are you converting `@datetime` to a varchar to compare it with a date for anyway? Its already a date, so you don't need to convert it to anything. Maybe thats the issue? Remove the convert.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot parameterize an identifier, such as a table name.  So, phrase this as:

```
Set @sql_nvarchar = N'
Select *
from ' + @tablename + '
where Date > @datetime
';

Set @sqlparams = N'@datetime datetime'
exec sp_executesql @sql_nvarchar, @sqlparams,
                   @datetime=@datetime
```

Comment: `@tablename` really should be quoted, otherwise this is just an injection problem waiting to happen. Especially as the OP is using a `nvarchar(MAX)` instead of `sysname`.

Comment: This fixed the issue... I'm not entirely sure what the original problem was (I think it may not even have anything to do with conversions and may have been a syntax error), but putting the parameter inside the dynamic SQL query and deleting @tablename from the parameters fixed the issue.